# Using property in File element's Source property in WiX

Tags: wix, installation

I am trying to use Property value in `Source` attribute of [File element](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/file.html), but getting this error:

```
error LGHT0103 : The system cannot find the file '[MYPROPERTY]'
```

Here is how property defined and used:

```
<Property Id="MYPROPERTY" Secure="yes" Value="myfile.xml" />
    ...
<File Id="MyFileId" Name="myfile.xml" Source="SubFolder\[MYPROPERTY]" KeyPath="yes" />
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The property defined via the *property*-Tag creates a public property in the MSI-Package which is a Windows Installer concept.

You are refering to this variable in the Source-Attribute of the File-Tag but that isn't the way you can use this property. You can only use them at runtime (e.g. to use them in Registry-Keys you create during the installation) but the Source-Attribut is resolved via compile-time of the package.

The Source-attribut of the File-Tag requires a path to variable that points to a location on the developer machine.

I assume you are looking for Wix precompiler directives:

```
<?define MyProperty = "C:\myfile.xml" ?>

<File Id="MyFileId" Name="myfile.xml" Source="$(var.MyProperty)" KeyPath="yes" />
```